# How do I unversion an .suo file in SVN for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I copied over a new Visual Studio project I've been working on to my Working Copy Structure.
Then in Windows Explorer I just right clicked and select "TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and Add to ignore list (recursively)" for the bin and obj folders.  Everything is great now except for the .suo file.

I've read about it, I know what it does.  I just can't get it out of the repository and/or un-versioned.

I also read this is not a physical file. So of course I can't see it in windows explorer and so cannot right click to select TortoiseSVN -> Unversion....".

And I have read that you can simply delete the .suo in the repository and everything will be find.
But when I do this I get the red exclamation mark and have a conflict.  When I try to update I get a conflict - something to the effect of "missing suo file".
So I have to go into show log and revert the changes of the revision where I deleted the suo.

How do just get rid of this thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a real file. Add it (`*.suo`) to ignore list (`svn:ignore` or `svn:global-ignores` since SVN 1.8) in the properties of the working copy and commit this change.

Comment: I did this.  But I think since its already there for this project it won't let me take it out. 
If I delete it I get conflicts and I have to revert back to before the delete or I can't update my working copy.
How do I get rid of this for the existing project?

Comment: in the working copy select the .suo file, make a rightclick go to TSVN and select delete. Now commit this delete.

Comment: Anyone working in a team environment *should not* follow magicandre1981's comment of how to delete the file to resolve this issue.  Doing an SVN delete will delete the file from everyone's machine on their next update.  Unless no one cares about their settings, breakpoints, etc. for that solution, they will be annoyed.   "TortoiseSVN -> Unversion and Add to ignore list" should work and is the appropriate method of removing a file from SVN while keeping the local copy. No down vote to @magicandre1981 because he is correct, that is how to get rid of it.